# Javascript page overlay without changing dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the process of learning JS, and am trying to add an integer (number of clicks) to all links on my page (This data is being parsed from an external API).

I am currently changing the link textContent for each link, and appending the integer to the end of the textContent, which works well for all text links, however I am having an issue with adding this click count integer to the images on the page.  What would be the best way to display the click count for images on the page. Would I be able to add the click count as an overlay on the image?

My code so far:

```
function ls(url) {
  var getURL = "url" + url;
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", getURL, "true");
  req.onload = function() {
    var resObj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      var rawLink = links[i].href; var linkText = links[i].textContent; var link = links[i].href.replace(/(.*)#?/, "$1");
      var escapedLink = escape(rawLink);
      if (rawLink in resObj) {
        links[i].textContent = linkText + " (" + resObj[rawLink] + ")";
      } else if (escapedLink in resObj) {
        links[i].textContent = linkText + " (" + resObj[escapedLink] + ")";
      }
    }
  };
```

This just appends the link count to the end of the textContent, how can I add this linkcount to images without messing up the page layout.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Consider providing a code example of what you have, and describe what you want in a better fashion. Right now, the answer is "maybe".

Comment: Mistakenly posted question before I was done!, Just updated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to wrap the images in a `<div>` and add the click count text as another child. Something like:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="..." alt="..." />
    <div class="click-count">10</div>
</div>
```

Then just style the click count text to be placed in a corner of the image using CSS. Possibly something like:

```
.image-wrapper { position: relative; }
.click-count { position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; }
```

To add the text to the image, you would have to do something like this (note that I am using jQuery for simplicity and because the question is tagged as such):

```
$( 'img' ).each( function() {
    // Test we need to add the click count
    ...

    // Add the click count number
    $( this ).wrap( '<div class="image-wrapper" />' ).append( '<div class="click-count">' + click_count + '</div>' );
});
```